# Python3 Tornado log twicely

Tags: python-3.x, tornado

I created a python script which generates captcha image.

```
import tornado.web, sys, json, io
class CaptchaHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        from PIL import Image
        from PIL import ImageDraw 
        from random import randint
        from PIL import ImageFont

        self.img = Image.new( 'RGB', (200,100), "black")
        pixels = self.img.load()

        for i in range(self.img.size[0]):
            for j in range(self.img.size[1]):
                pixels[i,j] = (i, j, 100)

        draw = ImageDraw.Draw(self.img)

        xy = ( randint(0, 180), randint(0, 80) )

        txt = str(randint(1000, 9999))

        font = ImageFont.truetype("arial.ttf", 28)
        draw.text( xy, txt, (255,255,255), font )
        del draw

        o = io.BytesIO()
        self.img.save(o, format="JPEG")
        s = o.getvalue()
        self.set_header('Content-type', "image/jpeg")   
        self.set_header('Content-length', len(s))   
        print(xy)
        self.write(s)  
class captcha_test(tornado.web.Application):
    def __init__(self):
        handlers = [(r"/captcha", CaptchaHandler),]
        tornado.web.Application.__init__(self, handlers,)

def test_captacha():
    application = captcha_test()
    application.listen(8086)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    test_captacha()
```

I am printing xy position and it prints twicly

Comment: Please, format your code.

Comment: @EugeneSoldatov finally I am able to format the code .... please reply as I stuck in it:(

Comment: What do you mean by "logging twice"? There are two messages in console?

Comment: yes, with two different numbers

Comment: Please, add console output to your question

Comment: `2015-02-04 14:58:35
6676 - text
162 - y position
2015-02-04 14:58:36`
6410 - text
130 - y position